# Am I doing this right on Keras?

Tags: keras, lstm, keras-layer

I am doing a keras implementation of sequence classification using 2 BLSTM and 2 FC layer. My data shape is (2655,219,835) where 219 is steps and 835 is number of features. Training is with 1800 intsances and test is with 855 instances. There are 4 classification groups- 0,1,2,3 and They are converted to vectors using to_categorical function. The network implementation code is below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(219,835)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128,return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128)))
model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
adam=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)   
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
history=model.fit(train_data, label_train,  epochs=30, validation_split=0.33, batch_size=128, verbose=1)
pred=model.predict(test_data)
```

Now, the problem is I am doing way too low accuracy than the reported accuracy in the paper. Could you please help me to find if I am making any mistake in here ?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please share the link of paper as well.

Comment: Also please show a sample output of `label_train`.

Comment: The label_train is:

array([[0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       ...,
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)

And I am not 'exactly' implementing a paper. I just needed to be sure that, the code is logically sound. 

Thanks !